# What are the differences between Koa and Express 4.0?

Tags: node.js, express, frameworks, koa

Koa and Express 4.0 are both fairly new, and from what I've read, Koa was made by the Express team.

From what I understand, Koa requires features of node that are only available in 0.11 (the unstable branch) of node, and also uses generators. Express 4.0 seems to only be the next version of the Express framework.

Are there any differences I am missing completely? Is it likely (based on what the Express team has publicly stated) that Koa and Express will merge at some point in the future?

Thanks!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Search engines should be your first resort before posting open-ended questions.

[From the Koa docs](https://github.com/koajs/koa/blob/master/docs/koa-vs-express.md):

> **Koa vs Express**
>
> Philosophically, Koa aims to "fix and replace node", whereas Express "augments node". Koa uses co to rid apps of callback
> hell and simplify error handling. It exposes its own `this.request` and
> `this.response` objects instead of node's `req` and `res` objects.
>
> Express, on the other hand, augments node's `req` and `res` objects with
> additional properties and methods and includes many other "framework"
> features, such as routing and templating, which Koa does not.
>
> Thus, Koa can be viewed as an abstraction of node.js's http modules,
> where as Express is an application framework for node.js.

...

> **Does Koa replace Express?**
>
> It's more like Connect, but a lot of the Express goodies were moved to
> the middleware level in Koa to help form a stronger foundation. This
> makes middleware more enjoyable and less error-prone to write, for the
> entire stack, not just the end application code.
>
> Typically many middleware would re-implement similar features, or even
> worse incorrectly implement them, when features like signed cookie
> secrets among others are typically application-specific, not
> middleware specific.

...

> **Why isn't Koa just Express 4.0?**
>
> Koa is a pretty large departure from what people know about Express,
> the design is fundamentally much different, so the migration from
> Express 3.0 to this Express 4.0 would effectively mean rewriting the
> entire application, so we thought it would be more appropriate to
> create a new library.

Comment: express seems to be dead by now. There is no active development going on for express new version.

Comment: @WitVault: Not sure what you're referring to, but ExpressJS got an update in June v4.14.0 » https://github.com/expressjs/express/releases

Comment: @August Yes very true but after that ? Do you see any commits? Check the commit graph https://github.com/expressjs/express/graphs/contributors

Comment: @WitVault I now humbly agree; I would have helped if I looked up the word recent.. lol! Thank you for correcting my perspective :-)

Comment: @WitVaul I checked the Koa commit graph https://github.com/koajs/koa/graphs/contributors and got basically the same impression.

Comment: @MichaelYutsis better stay away from such libraries then :)

Comment: One shouldn't measure activity of a project by number of commits. It should be just an evidence. Stable projects also have low commits.

Answer (score 8):

- Koa does not provides functionalities like Routing, Templating, Sending files and JSONP while the express does.
- koa exposes its own ctx.request and ctx.response objects instead of node's req and res objects  i.e. functions of the form (req, res, next), are incompatible with Koa.
- Koa can be viewed as an abstraction of node.js's http modules, where as Express is an application framework for node.js.

For more detailed answer you can visit official documents on this link :
https://github.com/koajs/koa/blob/master/docs/koa-vs-express.md

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20126610)

Comment: @SaravananSachi thanks for your suggestion.I have modified my answer can you review this now