# REST API w/ Nodejs + TypeScript in 2021

Tags: node.js, typescript, rest, express, koa

I have to build a rest API with Node.JS and TypeScript. I was about to use Express, but It looks like Koa, Fastify and Hapi could provide a better up-to-date experience.

So, what are the modern choices to build a rest api with node and TS in 2021?

Thanks!

Comment: The only one i know how to build api use typescript for enterprise application, you can see: http://www.solidbook.io

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**In my opinion, Express.js is the safe choice to go with for building REST APIs with TypeScript in 2021.**

Taking a look at the numbers and some other indicators of the popular web frameworks may give you some indication on what is mature and what you'll find community support for. You'll find the following:

| Framework | TypeScript support | GitHub stars | GitHub "used by" | SO tagged questions | npm weekly downloads |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [Express.js](https://github.com/expressjs/express) | `@types/express` | 51.6k (47.2k) | 8.8M (5.5M) | 72.7k (59.9k) | 15.2M (11M) |
| [Koa.js](https://github.com/koajs/koa) | `@types/koa` | 30.5k (28.4k) | 152k (106k) | (< 1k) | 733k (391k) |
| [Hapi.js](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi) | `@types/hapi__hapi` | 13k (12k) | 15.3k (5.9k) | (1.2k) | 333k (376k) |
| [Fastify](https://github.com/fastify/fastify) | Yes | 17k (13.4k) | 10.8k (5.3k) | (< 1k) | 155k (78k) |
| [Loopback 3/4](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback) | Yes | 13.3k/3.3k | 16.1k/3.4k | 1.2k | 34.8k |

*Data from January 17, 2021*
(within parenthesis are stats from February 4, 2020)

---

Read more about comparions about specific features:

- [How do Express and hapi compare to each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30469767/how-do-express-and-hapi-compare-to-each-other)
- [What are the differences between Koa and Express 4.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23140968/what-are-the-differences-between-koa-and-express-4-0)

Resources used:

- https://www.githubcompare.com/expressjs/express+strongloop/loopback+hapijs/hapi+koajs/koa+fastify/fastify
- https://stars.przemeknowak.com/
- https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/

---

**EDIT:** Added data from 2021

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  A problem I find with looking at the data, is that Express being the oldest and historically a very successfull NPM package, his stats tends to prevent us to see upcoming new solutions. For example, looking at npm trends makes the choice obvious, but at the same time, makes the "express trust" obvious: https://www.npmtrends.com/express-vs-koa-vs-fastify-vs-hapi

Comment: I agree. From the data, seems like Fastify is the "up-and-comer" and is perhaps your most promising choice if you are indeed looking for innovation. However, I'd argue that these frameworks rarely change, web frameworks have been "figured out". If you're looking for something more exotic, check out GraphQL.

Answer (score 1):

I also find this ressource wich looks quite promising and serious about creating rest API: http://restify.com/ it does work with TypeScript, and it looks meant to create exclusively REST apis. Worth a look!

Answer (score 1):

I've been using [Koa](https://koajs.com/) for the past year or so, and I've greatly enjoyed it.

It was actually developed by the same people that developed Express, it just had enough breaking changes from past versions of Express that they decided to give it a new name.

I find the middleware to be less confusing with Koa, and using `ctx` instead of separate `req` and `res` parameters to be much more friendly to read. It comes with a glowing recommendation from me, no complaints so far.